# How to inline 'skewed' li's with no margin between

Tags: html, css, skew

I need help placing 4 inline li's in a div, but, those li's need to be 'horizontally skewed'.
This is what I need to do: (sorry about the link but stack won't let me place pictures)

https://www.flickr.com/photos/107597387@N08/

I can't use the css transform -skew tool because it would skew the content inside the element too (there's an image for each one), and it would also cut the first and last box.

I tried to use polygon clip-path, but i cant manage to clear the space between those boxes.

HTML:

`<div id="someDiv" class="colors">
    <ul>
        <li id="c1" class="color">color1</li>
        <li id="c2" class="color">color2</li>
        <li id="c3" class="color">color3</li>
        <li id="c4" class="color">color4</li>
    </ul>
</div`

CSS:

```
.colors ul li{
display: inline-block;
list-style: none;
float: left;
width: 25%;
height: auto;
margin-right: 0;
padding-top: 5%;
padding-bottom: 5%;
cursor: pointer;
color: white;
}
.color{
   -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
   clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
#c1{
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
    background-color: #562b44;
    }
#c2{
    background-color: #abf6d6;
    }
#c3{
    background-color: #aa2d53;
    }
#c4{
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    background-color: #dca096;
    }
```

Here's a JSFiddle showing what's happening:
https://jsfiddle.net/pnvm/zz83zxzd/3/

CSS Shapes don't yet work on older browsers, so I haven't even tried them.

I'm stuck.. Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: you can place image here using image button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if i'm wrong but can't you do this with `margin-left` eg :

```
.colors ul li{
    margin-left:-6.2%
}
.colors ul li:first-child{
    margin-left:0px
}
.color{
    text-indent:6%
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest itssajan :)
I had already tried tweaking the margins, but that brings one other problem:
The whole structure becomes smaller than the page's full width.

Comment: The time's running really short, so i have to stick to this solution and tweak the resulting problems after it.
I've considered your answer as a full solution. Ty once again itssajan